# Why are we limited to only the most general UTIs when using iOS open in feature?

Tags: ios7, plist, info.plist, uti

Am trying to create an app which supports "open in" for pdf and ppt files. Added this xml to info-plist

```
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
        <array>
            <string>Icon1.png</string>
            <string>Icon2.png</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My Document</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Viewer</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Alternate</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.adobe.pdf </string>
            <string>com.microsoft.powerpoint.​ppt</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

Surprisingly it doesn't work, but if I replace the two entries in the LSIContentTypes array with public.item everything works smoothly. Anyone see where te eerror is?